# Why are my callbacks not firing with async queue?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I am using [async queue](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.QueueObject) to process a huge amount of data. The queue works great until I try to perform an update in the database with [MongoDB findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) method.

I first establish the queue, and start pushing objects to it from a Node Stream:

```
//Create queue to process all items
let q = async.queue(processLink, 2);

// Create Node Stream
let createStream = function () {
    let stream = fs.createReadStream(LinkData, {encoding: 'utf8'});
    let parser = JSONStream.parse('RECDATA.*');
    return stream.pipe(parser);
};

//Listen to 'data' event on stream and add object to queue
createStream().on('data', function(link){
    q.push(link)
});
```

Here is my task function, 'processLink'. It is here, that I am having trouble tracking down the problem. Whenever the findOneAndUpdate callback is fired, it enters one of the conditional blocks, and I am getting the message logged out to the console, but when I call the async callback processComplete(), the task does not finish as expected.

As the title suggests, Why are my async callbacks not completing each task?

```
function processLink(link, processComplete){
    if(_.includes(link.URL, 'www.usda.gov') && _.includes(link.URL, '?recid=')){
        let url_items = _.split(link.URL, '=',2);
        let facilityOrgID = url_items[1];
        let update = {$push: {"links": link}};

        if(_.isNumber(parseInt(facilityOrgID)) && facilityOrgID.length > 4 ){

            Facility.findOneAndUpdate({facilityOrgID: parseInt(facilityOrgID)}, update, (err, result) => {

                if(err !== null){
                    console.log("Error:",err);
                    return processComplete(err); /** NOT FIRING **/
                } else if(err === null && result !== null){

                    console.log("Link added to:", result.name);
                    return processComplete(); /** NOT FIRING **/ 
                }else if(err === null && result === null){

                    console.log('Facility not in database');
                    processComplete(); /** NOT FIRING **/ 
                }else{
                    console.log('Something has gone terrible wrong');
                }
            });

        }else{
            console.log("Invalid facilityID");
            return processComplete();
        }

    }else{
        console.log('Link Discarded:', link.URL);
        processComplete(); /** Fires normally **/ 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem this morning. The callbacks were fine, but rather there was a conditional state of the data I was not aware of, thus it was leading to a state in which the code would never call the processComplete() callback.

If anyone else is finding themselves in a similar bind, and you have tons of data, I would ensure that your data is being reported accurately and there are not some edge cases that were not being processed as expected.